# I can't parsed my google 'local state address' variable to news api url

Tags: javascript, html

was already obtain the user address through geocoding reverse, but somehow the 'state' variable can't parsed to the news api url. The getWeatherData function works well since it was 'researched' and 'inspired' from someone. But the for getNewsData function I can't parsed the address variable into the url. Please help guys.

```
  $(document).ready(function getWeather() {

  var lat;
  var lon;
  var state;
  var timevar;


  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);


  } else {
    alert("Geolocation services are not supported by your web browser.");
  }

  function success(position) {
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lon = position.coords.longitude;

    timevar = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10);
    // var state;

    var reversegeocodingapi = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+lat+","+lon+"&key=mykey";
    $.getJSON(reversegeocodingapi, function(place) {
      for (var i=0; i<place.results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
        if (place.results[0].address_components[i].types[0]==="locality") {
          var city = place.results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
          $("#city").html(city.toUpperCase());
        }
        if (place.results[0].address_components[i].types[0]==="administrative_area_level_1") {
          var state = place.results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
          $("#state").html(state.toUpperCase());
          }
      }
    }); //end getJSON
    getWeatherData(lat, lon);
    getNewsData(state,timevar);
  } //end success


  function error() {
    var alerted = localStorage.getItem('alerted') || '';
    if (alerted != 'yes') {
     alert("Sorry, I don't know where you are, abort local news/weather service.");
     localStorage.setItem('alerted','yes');
    }

  }

  function getWeatherData(latitude, longitude) {
    var weatherapiurl = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/mykey/"+lat+","+lon+"?callback=?"
    $.getJSON(weatherapiurl, function(weatherdata) {
      var tempf = Math.round(weatherdata.currently.temperature);
      $("#temp").html(tempf + "°");
      var tempc = Math.round(((weatherdata.currently.temperature)-32)/(9/5));
      var feelslikef = Math.round(weatherdata.currently.apparentTemperature);
      $("#feels-like").html("Feels Like: " + feelslikef + "°F");
      var feelslikec =  
      ...........
      ...........
      });//end f click
    }); //end getJSON
  }; //end getWeatherData



  function getNewsData(localstate,date0,date1) {



    // timevar = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10);
    var url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q='+state+'&from='+timevar+'&to='+timevar+'&sortBy=popularity&apiKey=mykey/'+'?callback=?';
    // var url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=techcrunch&apiKey=mykey';

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if ( this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200 ) {
            var data = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText).articles;

            console.log(data);

            var articles = data.map(mapToArticle);
            var contentDiv = document.getElementById('content');

            contentDiv.innerHTML = createTemplate(articles);
        }
    }

    xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xhttp.send();

    function mapToArticle(item) {
        return {
            url: item.url,
            title: item.title,
            author: item.author,
            date: item.publishedAt,
            img: item.urlToImage ? item.urlToImage : null,
            description: item.description
        };
    }

    function formatTime(timestr) {
      return timestr.substr(0, 10);
    }

    function createTemplate(articles) {
        return articles.reduce(function(tmpl, article) {
            tmpl += `
            <article>
                <h2><a class="article-header" href="${article.url}">${article.title}</a></h2>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img class="img-fluid rounded mb-3" src="${article.img}"  />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <p class="date">${formatTime(article.date)}</p>
                        <p class="author">by ${article.author}</p>
                        <div>${article.description}</div>
                        <a class="btn-more" href="${article.url}">read more</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </article>
            `;

            return tmpl;
        }, '');
    }
  }




}); //end ready
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getJSON` is an asynchronous call yet you are trying to use the result of it outside the callback meaning that you are trying to access the state variable before anything has been assigned to it. Just move you function calls inside the callback and you should be right.

```
$.getJSON(reversegeocodingapi, function(place) {
  for (var i=0; i<place.results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
    if (place.results[0].address_components[i].types[0]==="locality") {
      var city = place.results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
      $("#city").html(city.toUpperCase());
    }
    if (place.results[0].address_components[i].types[0]==="administrative_area_level_1") {
      var state = place.results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
      $("#state").html(state.toUpperCase());
      }
  }
  getWeatherData(lat, lon);
  getNewsData(state,timevar)
}); //end getJSON
```

Comment: hi Simon, thank you so much for the quick response. I try your solution but still having no luck. however I feel like I am getting very close of what I want to achieve here. the browser return a 401 error, but that cannot be the case, because I try to use a static url with my key and it renders well. the 401 error shows that the 'state' variable is still 'undefined', I am suspect may be the news api, at some sense prevent the ?callback=? from rendering ? would love to hear from you.

Comment: All I can suggest is debugging your code to see if your mappings to the state variable are correct. Just step through it using a `debugger` statement and make sure the value you are trying to use is actually correct.

Comment: Hi Simon, I got it, I make it work by following your logic and moving the whole block of getNewsData function code inside the 'endJson' and it works now. thanks for the advice. Greatly appreciated.